# Can we generate dynamic key for typescript enums?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

First of all i am a beginner on typescript. I came from JavaScript world. Please forgive me, if i asked something wrong.

What i want?

```
enum Add {
  PREFIX = 'ADD',
  ROUTE_PREFIX = 'add'
}

export CrudAdd {
  `${Add.PREFIX}_CUSTOMER` = `${Add.ROUTE_PREFIX}-customer`,
  // ....
}
```

I dont want to type `*_CUSTOMER`, all the time.

This can be achived in Plain JS like

```
const obj = {
  `${Add.PREFIX}_CUSTOMER`: `${Add.ROUTE_PREFIX}-customer`
}
```

Somewhere i read after complilation enum is nothing but an JS object.

Can i achive this behaviour?

Again, i am soory for this question.

Comment: What is `CrudAdd`? enum? interface?

Answer (score 2):

Two parts to what you are looking for -

1. You can assign a key and value to the object accessing the property as a collection  -

   ```
   obj[`${Add.PREFIX}_CUSTOMER`] = `${Add.ROUTE_PREFIX}-customer`;
   ```
2. You can iterate over the `enum` and assign it values using `Object.keys(YourEnum)`, like -

   ```
   enum Add {
     PREFIX = 'ADD',
     ROUTE_PREFIX = 'add'
   }

   export const obj = {
   };

   Object.keys(Add).forEach(x=>{
     obj[x] = Add[x];
   });

   console.log(obj);
   ```

Check the [console in this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xru31b)